# Configuración Prettier y saltos de linea

Tags: html

Tengo un problema con la configuración de prettier.

En los html, en las lineas de links javascript, por ejemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom-components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
```

Me las formatea, con un formato que no lo considero correcto

```
<link 
rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css" 
href="custom-components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.min.css"
>
```

¿Alguien sabe como evitarlo? He probado muchas configuraciones, revisado su documentación, pero no veo nada en este aspecto.

He revisado la configuración `--print-width <int>` cambiandola por varios valores, 200, 500... y no veo cambio alguno, me sigue haciendo el salto de línea.

Comment: fijate que no sea el editor el que te está sobreescribiendo las preferencias en vscode `HTML › Format: Wrap Line Length` está en 120 por defecto, aumenta ahí, vas a tener que cerrarlo y volverlo a abrir

Comment: He probado a desactivarlo y parece que estas en lo cierto, ahora ya coge el de prettier correctamente. Gracias a los dos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La opción que buscas es: `--print-width <int>` si lo usas por CLI o `printWidth: <int>` si lo configuras desde un archivo, en la misma documentación advierten que no es conveniente que sea mayor a 80 el número que es la configuración estándar y un estándar de la industria también.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html

Answer (score -1):

por si alguien no sabe bien como hacerlo(como fue mi caso) pueden hacerlo dedla siguiente forma:
1- en vscode tocar el engranaje e ir a configuracion
2- en la configuracion buscar prettier
3- bajar hasta encontrar la opcion Prettier: print width y cambiar el valor de 80 a 120(es el que esta por defecto en vscode) o al valor que desees

Comment: No es recomendable agregar un número mayor a 80